# How to show decoration in place of event names in dojo calendar?

Tags: events, dojo, calendar

We are using dojo calendar in our web application. We are also showing events on the calendar.

In the matrix view we do not need to show event names. But just some indicator that there are some events on that day. e.g. If 15 Jan has 5 events, currently it shows 5 events names on the 15 Jan cell in the matrix view.

See below

[image]

We now want that instead of the 5 events names, we can show some indicator like may be some different color or a vertical line to indicate that there are events on 15 jan, and when you click on the cell you will then get the details of all events on the date.

See below

[image]

Is there any setting in dojo calendar which can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/calendar/tests/)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should go first on this : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#grid-cell-styling, so you can change the css to the cell look like what you want.